# Animation wobbles with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having a problem where the animation I'm trying running causes the text (and I think certain elements) to shake and wobble ever-so-slightly so as to not look great. You can see a working example of it here:

http://winterstations.com/

The part illustrating the "days left" over the register menu item.

HTML Fragment:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li></a><a href="register.php">REGISTER</a><div id="register_hover"><span>REGISTER NOW!</span><div id="register_hover_arrow"></div></div></li>
</ul>
```

CSS Fragment:

```
#menu {
    text-align: justify;
    width: 50em;
    height: 1em;
}

#menu li {
    position: relative;
}

#register_hover {
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    background-color: #FFA200;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    letter-spacing: 0.25em;
    font-weight: normal;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 2px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    height: 1.5em;
    width: 300%;
    top: -2.5em;
    left: -100%;
}

#register_hover span {
    position: relative;
    top: .25em;
    z-index: 2;
}

#register_hover_arrow {
    margin: 0 auto;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-.8em) rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: translateY(-.8em) rotate(45deg);
    transform: translateY(-.8em) rotate(45deg);
    background-color: #FFA200;
    position: relative;
    height: 1em;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 1em;
    top: .6em;
}
```

Javascript fragment:

```
var animateDeadlineAlert = function() {
    var originalYOffset = $('#register_hover').css('top');
    $('#register_hover').animate({
        'top': '-3em'
    }, function() {
        $(this).animate({
            'top': originalYOffset
        }, function() {
            animateDeadlineAlert();
        });
    });
};

animateDeadlineAlert();
```

JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/wd0xj3rb/

Comment: Are CSS animations a possibility?

Comment: Yeah, and they're likely what I'll just end up doing but I wanted to know why this didn't work conceptually

Comment: It probably doesn't help that the `top` property is rapidly switching between pixels and ems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using translate is far more performant than animating the `top` value with jQuery. Animating elements using `transform` will [not trigger](http://csstriggers.com/#transform) `layout` or `paint`, which is why it is far more performant than letting jQuery manually calculate the correct position based on pixels.

Paul Lewis [gave an excellent talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RCFQu0hK6bU#t=4m02s), which is well worth the watch, in which he describes the problem you are encountering, in which your element's movement is jittery.

Simply put: use `transform` whenever possible. The problem you have described seems like a good fit to me.

```css
.hover {
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-animation: 1s hover-deadline infinite alternate;
  ease;
  animation: 1s hover-deadline infinite alternate;
  ease;
  padding: 1em;
  background: tomato;
  color: white;
  font: bold 1em sans-serif;
}
@-webkit-keyframes hover-deadline {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(25px)
  }
}
@keyframes hover-deadline {
  from {
   transform: translateY(0px)
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(25px)
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="hover">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the Jason's answer, exactly, because is a valuable solution. I've made an example to illustrate this.

In this example i'm using the linear function to accomplish the same effect of the animation that you have in your code.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
#menu {
  text-align: justify;
  width: 50em;
  height: 1em;
}
#menu li {
  position: relative;
  width: 5em;
  list-style-type: none;
}
#register_hover {
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  background-color: #FFA200;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  letter-spacing: 0.25em;
  font-weight: normal;
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 2px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  height: 1.5em;
  width: 300%;
  top: -2.5em;
  left: -100%;
  animation: anim 0.4s linear infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation: anim 0.4s linear infinite alternate;
}
#register_hover span {
  position: relative;
  top: .25em;
  z-index: 2;
}
#register_hover_arrow {
  margin: 0 auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateY(-.8em) rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: translateY(-.8em) rotate(45deg);
  transform: translateY(-.8em) rotate(45deg);
  background-color: #FFA200;
  position: relative;
  height: 1em;
  z-index: 1;
  width: 1em;
  top: .6em;
}
@keyframes anim {
  from {
    transform: translateY(-10px)
  }
  to {
    transform: translateY(0px)
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-10px)
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px)
  }
}
```

```html
<br />
<br />
<ul id="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="register.php">REGISTER</a>
    <div id="register_hover"><span>REGISTER NOW!</span>
      <div id="register_hover_arrow"></div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jason got it right. It is preferred to always use CSS3 animations when possible. However, it should have worked fine with JS as well since the animation is quite simple. Your problem was that you used a totally different div in order to create the bottom arrow. You could have done it simply by using `:after`

Here is a combined example of this concept and the solution @Jason suggested

https://jsfiddle.net/0LLcc0bb/